# Black hole singularity in string theory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, singularities

There is a consensus in theoretical physics that the singularity at the center of a black hole is a mathematical consequence of the fact that general relativity is a classical theory which does not account for quantum mechanical effects. It is expected that the singularity would be replaced by something else in a theory of quantum gravity. 
Since string theory is a theory of quantum gravity, I am interested in what does it have to say about what lies in the center of a black hole where quantum mechanical effects become important. Has anyone worked that out and what were the results?